# update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy for arptables not registered; not setting

Tags: debian, iptables, kvm, debian-buster, nftables

I've Debian 10 (Buster) KVM guest machines on a Buster host. Trying to switch to the legacy `iptables` on VMs following [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables)

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-nft
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-nft
```

While other three succeeds, `arptables` update fails with the message

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy for arptables not registered; not setting
```

Is there a workaround?

If you're curious, guest machines are nodes of a Kubernetes (v1.18) cluster initiated with kubeadm. Network plugin is [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org). Everything works with default `nftables` settings except that [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf) controller errors

```
 1 reflector.go:125] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20190620085101-78d2af792bab/tools/cache/reflector.go:98: Failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/metallb-system/configmaps?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dconfig&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

When I `ping 10.96.0.1` from guest VM, I get

```
PING 10.96.0.1 (10.96.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 94.157.208.1 icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
From 94.157.208.1 icmp_seq=2 Packet filtered
...

--- 10.96.0.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +7 errors, 100% packet loss, time 15ms
```

Answer (score 8):

At first you need to install legacy packages:

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y iptables arptables ebtables
```

And then update alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
sudo update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

Comment: It didn't work. k8s 1.19 doesn't require compatibility

Comment: Does not work on my Ubuntu 18.04. It says that the packages are already installed and still fails with the error of the OP.

Comment: On Debian 11 it works. Thank you.