# nginx-ingress-controller - CrashLoopBackOff - kubernetes on proxmox (kvm)

Tags: kubernetes, crash, kubernetes-ingress, kvm, proxmox

I'm running a kubernetes cluster hostet inside 4 kvm, managed by proxmox. After installing the nginx-ingress-controller with

```
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true -n nginx-ingress
```

the controller is crashing (crashloop) . The logs don't really help (or i don't know where to look exactly)

thanks Peter

herer the cluster pods:

```
root@sedeka78:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-jv2mx                         1/1     Running            0          83m   10.244.0.9    sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-vwrzb                         1/1     Running            0          83m   10.244.0.6    sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-sedeka78                                    1/1     Running            2          84m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-sedeka78                          1/1     Running            2          84m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-sedeka78                 1/1     Running            4          84m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-fxvfh                      1/1     Running            0          83m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-h6btb                      1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.79   sedeka79   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-m6dw2                      1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.80   sedeka80   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-flannel-ds-amd64-wgtqb                      1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.81   sedeka81   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-5dvdg                                 1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.80   sedeka80   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-89pf7                                 1/1     Running            0          83m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-hhgtf                                 1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.79   sedeka79   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-kshnn                                 1/1     Running            1          78m   10.10.10.81   sedeka81   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-sedeka78                          1/1     Running            5          84m   10.10.10.78   sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-6b4884c9d5-4trgg       1/1     Running            0          80m   10.244.0.8    sedeka78   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7bfbb48676-q6c2t            1/1     Running            0          80m   10.244.0.7    sedeka78   <none>           <none>
nginx-ingress          nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5         0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   19         45m   10.244.1.2    sedeka81   <none>           <none>
nginx-ingress          nginx-ingress-default-backend-7c868597f4-8q9n7   1/1     Running            0          45m   10.244.4.2    sedeka80   <none>           <none>
root@sedeka78:~#
```

here the logs of the controller:

```
root@sedeka78:~# kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5 -n nginx-ingress -v10
I0705 14:31:41.152337   11692 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /home/kubernetes/.kube/config
I0705 14:31:41.170664   11692 cached_discovery.go:114] returning cached discovery info from /root/.kube/cache/discovery/10.10.10.78_6443/servergroups.json
I0705 14:31:41.174651   11692 cached_discovery.go:71] returning cached discovery info from
```

...

```
I0705 14:31:41.189379   11692 cached_discovery.go:71] returning cached discovery info from /root/.kube/cache/discovery/10.10.10.78_6443/batch/v1beta1/serverresources.json
I0705 14:31:41.189481   11692 cached_discovery.go:71] returning cached discovery info from /root/.kube/cache/discovery/10.10.10.78_6443/batch/v1/serverresources.json
I0705 14:31:41.189560   11692 cached_discovery.go:71] returning cached discovery info from /root/.kube/cache/discovery/10.10.10.78_6443/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json
I0705 14:31:41.192043   11692 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.18.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e6503f8" 'https://10.10.10.78:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5'
I0705 14:31:41.222314   11692 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://10.10.10.78:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5 200 OK in 30 milliseconds
I0705 14:31:41.222588   11692 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0705 14:31:41.222611   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0705 14:31:41.222771   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I0705 14:31:41.222812   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 12:31:41 GMT
I0705 14:31:41.223225   11692 request.go:1068] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5","generateName":"nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-","namespace":"nginx-ingress","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5","uid":"778a9c24-9785-462e-9e1e-137a1aa08c87","resourceVersion":"10435","creationTimestamp":"2020-07-05T11:54:55Z","labels":{"app":"nginx-ingress","app.kubernetes.io/component":"controller","component":"controller","pod-template-hash":"57f4b84b5","release":"nginx-ingress"},"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5","uid":"b9c42590-7efb-46d2-b37c-cec3a994bf4e","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}],"managedFields":[{"manager":"kube-controller-manager","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-07-05T11:54:55Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:metadata":{"f:generateName":{},"f:labels":{".":{},"f:app":{},"f:app.kubernetes.io/component":{},"f:component":{},"f:pod-template-hash":{},"f:release":{}},"f:ownerReferences":{".":{},"k:{\"uid\":\"b9c42590-7efb-46d2-b37c-cec3a994bf4e\"}":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:blockOwnerDeletion":{},"f:controller":{},"f:kind":{},"f:name":{},"f:uid":{}}}},"f:spec":{"f:containers":{"k:{\"name\":\"nginx-ingress-controller\"}":{".":{},"f:args":{},"f:env":{".":{},"k:{\"name\":\"POD_NAME\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:valueFrom":{".":{},"f:fieldRef":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:fieldPath":{}}}},"k:{\"name\":\"POD_NAMESPACE\"}":{".":{},"f:name":{},"f:valueFrom":{".":{},"f:fieldRef":{".":{},"f:apiVersion":{},"f:fieldPath":{}}}}},"f:image":{},"f:imagePullPolicy":{},"f:livenessProbe":{".":{},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:httpGet":{".":{},"f:path":{},"f:port":{},"f:scheme":{}},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:name":{},"f:ports":{".":{},"k:{\"containerPort\":80,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}},"k:{\"containerPort\":443,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}":{".":{},"f:containerPort":{},"f:name":{},"f:protocol":{}}},"f:readinessProbe":{".":{},"f:failureThreshold":{},"f:httpGet":{".":{},"f:path":{},"f:port":{},"f:scheme":{}},"f:initialDelaySeconds":{},"f:periodSeconds":{},"f:successThreshold":{},"f:timeoutSeconds":{}},"f:resources":{},"f:securityContext":{".":{},"f:allowPrivilegeEscalation":{},"f:capabilities":{".":{},"f:add":{},"f:drop":{}},"f:runAsUser":{}},"f:terminationMessagePath":{},"f:terminationMessagePolicy":{}}},"f:dnsPolicy":{},"f:enableServiceLinks":{},"f:restartPolicy":{},"f:schedulerName":{},"f:securityContext":{},"f:serviceAccount":{},"f:serviceAccountName":{},"f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds":{}}}},{"manager":"kubelet","operation":"Update","apiVersion":"v1","time":"2020-07-05T12:27:53Z","fieldsType":"FieldsV1","fieldsV1":{"f:status":{"f:conditions":{"k:{\"type\":\"ContainersReady\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:message":{},"f:reason":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}},"k:{\"type\":\"Initialized\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}},"k:{\"type\":\"Ready\"}":{".":{},"f:lastProbeTime":{},"f:lastTransitionTime":{},"f:message":{},"f:reason":{},"f:status":{},"f:type":{}}},"f:containerStatuses":{},"f:hostIP":{},"f:phase":{},"f:podIP":{},"f:podIPs":{".":{},"k:{\"ip\":\"10.244.1.2\"}":{".":{},"f:ip":{}}},"f:startTime":{}}}}]},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8","secret":{"secretName":"nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8","defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"nginx-ingress-controller","image":"quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0","args":["/nginx-ingress-controller","--default-backend-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-default-backend","--publish-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller","--election-id=ingress-controller-leader","--ingress-class=nginx","--configmap=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller"],"ports":[{"name":"http","containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"},{"name":"https","containerPort":443,"protocol":"TCP"}],"env":[{"name":"POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"apiVersion":"v1","fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"POD_NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"apiVersion":"v1","fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}}],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"}],"livenessProbe":{"httpGet":{"path":"/healthz","port":10254,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":10,"timeoutSeconds":1,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"failureThreshold":3},"readinessProbe":{"httpGet":{"path":"/healthz","port":10254,"scheme":"HTTP"},"initialDelaySeconds":10,"timeoutSeconds":1,"periodSeconds":10,"successThreshold":1,"failureThreshold":3},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent","securityContext":{"capabilities":{"add":["NET_BIND_SERVICE"],"drop":["ALL"]},"runAsUser":101,"allowPrivilegeEscalation":true}}],"restartPolicy":"Always","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":60,"dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst","serviceAccountName":"nginx-ingress","serviceAccount":"nginx-ingress","nodeName":"sedeka81","securityContext":{},"schedulerName":"default-scheduler","tolerations":[{"key":"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoExecute","tolerationSeconds":300},{"key":"node.kubernetes.io/unreachable","operator":"Exists","effect":"NoExecute","tolerationSeconds":300}],"priority":0,"enableServiceLinks":true},"status":{"phase":"Running","conditions":[{"type":"Initialized","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2020-07-05T11:54:56Z"},{"type":"Ready","status":"False","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2020-07-05T11:54:56Z","reason":"ContainersNotReady","message":"containers with unready status: [nginx-ingress-controller]"},{"type":"ContainersReady","status":"False","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2020-07-05T11:54:56Z","reason":"ContainersNotReady","message":"containers with unready status: [nginx-ingress-controller]"},{"type":"PodScheduled","status":"True","lastProbeTime":null,"lastTransitionTime":"2020-07-05T11:54:56Z"}],"hostIP":"10.10.10.81","podIP":"10.244.1.2","podIPs":[{"ip":"10.244.1.2"}],"startTime":"2020-07-05T11:54:56Z","containerStatuses":[{"name":"nginx-ingress-controller","state":{"waiting":{"reason":"CrashLoopBackOff","message":"back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=nginx-ingress-controller pod=nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5_nginx-ingress(778a9c24-9785-462e-9e1e-137a1aa08c87)"}},"lastState":{"terminated":{"exitCode":143,"reason":"Error","startedAt":"2020-07-05T12:27:23Z","finishedAt":"2020-07-05T12:27:53Z","containerID":"docker://4b7d69c47884790031e665801e282dafd8ea5dfaf97d54c6659d894d88af5a7a"}},"ready":false,"restartCount":15,"image":"quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0","imageID":"docker-pullable://quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:251e733bf41cdf726092e079d32eed51791746560fff4d59cf067508ed635287","containerID":"docker://4b7d69c47884790031e665801e282dafd8ea5dfaf97d54c6659d894d88af5a7a","started":false}],"qosClass":"BestEffort"}}
I0705 14:31:41.239523   11692 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.18.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/e6503f8" 'https://10.10.10.78:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5/log'
I0705 14:31:41.247040   11692 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://10.10.10.78:6443/api/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/pods/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5/log 200 OK in 7 milliseconds
I0705 14:31:41.247125   11692 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0705 14:31:41.247146   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: text/plain
I0705 14:31:41.247164   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 12:31:41 GMT
I0705 14:31:41.247182   11692 round_trippers.go:452]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       0.32.0
  Build:         git-446845114
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.17.10

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I0705 12:27:23.597622       8 flags.go:204] Watching for Ingress class: nginx
W0705 12:27:23.598540       8 flags.go:249] SSL certificate chain completion is disabled (--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false)
W0705 12:27:23.598663       8 client_config.go:543] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0705 12:27:23.599666       8 main.go:220] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
```

And here:

```
root@sedeka78:~# kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5 -n nginx-ingress
Name:         nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5
Namespace:    nginx-ingress
Priority:     0
Node:         sedeka81/10.10.10.81
Start Time:   Sun, 05 Jul 2020 13:54:56 +0200
Labels:       app=nginx-ingress
              app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
              component=controller
              pod-template-hash=57f4b84b5
              release=nginx-ingress
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.2
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.2
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5
Containers:
  nginx-ingress-controller:
    Container ID:  docker://545ed277d1a039cd36b0d18a66d1f58c8b44f3fc5e4cacdcde84cc68e763b0e8
    Image:         quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:251e733bf41cdf726092e079d32eed51791746560fff4d59cf067508ed635287
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-default-backend
      --publish-service=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller
      --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
      --ingress-class=nginx
      --configmap=nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    143
      Started:      Sun, 05 Jul 2020 14:33:33 +0200
      Finished:     Sun, 05 Jul 2020 14:34:03 +0200
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  17
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  nginx-ingress (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  nginx-ingress-token-rmhf8
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>            default-scheduler  Successfully assigned nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller-57f4b84b5-ldkk5 to sedeka81
  Normal   Pulling    41m                  kubelet, sedeka81  Pulling image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0"
  Normal   Pulled     41m                  kubelet, sedeka81  Successfully pulled image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0"
  Normal   Created    40m (x3 over 41m)    kubelet, sedeka81  Created container nginx-ingress-controller
  Normal   Started    40m (x3 over 41m)    kubelet, sedeka81  Started container nginx-ingress-controller
  Normal   Killing    40m (x2 over 40m)    kubelet, sedeka81  Container nginx-ingress-controller failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled     40m (x2 over 40m)    kubelet, sedeka81  Container image "quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.32.0" already present on machine
  Warning  Unhealthy  40m (x6 over 41m)    kubelet, sedeka81  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.1.2:10254/healthz: dial tcp 10.244.1.2:10254: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  21m (x33 over 41m)   kubelet, sedeka81  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.244.1.2:10254/healthz: dial tcp 10.244.1.2:10254: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    97s (x148 over 38m)  kubelet, sedeka81  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED
I used DEBIAN10 (Buster) and arptables wasn't in the legacy mode.

Here is the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install -y iptables arptables ebtables


update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-nft
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-nft
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-nft
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-nft
```

See here:
[update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy for arptables not registered; not setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62441725/update-alternatives-error-alternative-usr-sbin-arptables-legacy-for-arptables)

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about certificate problem:

```
curl [10.96.0.1:443](https://10.96.0.1/) curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More details here: [curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above
```

You have  two options to get this to work:

1. Use cURL with  `-k`  option which allows curl to make insecure connections, that is cURL does not verify the certificate.
2. Add the root CA (the CA signing the server certificate) to  `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

I think you should use option 2 as it's the option that ensures that you are connecting to secure FTP server.

Speaking about readiness and liveness probes failures:

**When CPU is consumed in 100% on node, then nginx-ingress-controller immediatelly fail**, because it doesn't have  `requests`  CPU so it answers too long for http://:.../healthz (1 sec if I remember).

You should have CPU  `requests`  for nginx-ingress-controller or never let pods in node to use 100% of CPU, which sounds impossible to control.

Also you can change flannel to calico.
Remove flannel, installl calico with the following commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/etcd.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/rbac.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml
```

Take a look: [limits-requests-nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4735), [limit-range-pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod), [flannel-calico-nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2968), [local-issuer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611640/curl-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).

Comment: Thank you! but it didn't solve teh problem i have the root- ca at this place
root@sedeka78:~# cd /etc/ssl/certs/
root@sedeka78:/etc/ssl/certs# ls -al | grep ca-cert*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 200408 Jul  5 13:08 ca-certificates.crt
root@sedeka78:/etc/ssl/certs#
maybe i have a communication problem between the nodes?
I will reinstall the cluster with calico maybe this will help

Comment: Did you manage to reinstall cluster with new network plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin point exactly what is the issue but nginx ingress controller is in `CrashLoopBackOff` because it can not reach the Kubernetes API Server at `https://10.96.0.1:443`. Probably there is some network or connectivity issue between the nginx ingress controller pod and Kubernetes API Server.

Try to `curl https://10.96.0.1:443` from another pod.

Comment: root@sedeka79:~# curl https://10.96.0.1:443
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
root@sedeka79:~#